# Swagger doesnt show inherited objects

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a class "SubModel" which inherits from class "SuperModel". My REST request returns an object of one of these classes. Now i want to document that in my Swagger UI that either an object of SubModel OR an object of SuperModel will be returned. I googled for this use case and found the @ApiModel annotations but they dont work, does anybody have an idea what i´m doing wrong here?

```
@ApiModel(value = "SuperModel", discriminator = "foo", subTypes = { 
SubModel.class })
public class SuperModel
{
    @ApiModelProperty(required = true)
    private String foo;

    public String getFoo() {
        return this.foo;
    }

    public void setFoo( String foo ) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}  

@ApiModel(value = "SubModel")
public class SubModel extends SuperModel
{
    private int    number;

    public int getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

    public void setNumber( int number ) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

What i see in Swagger UI is only:

```
SuperModel {
  foo (string)
}
```

I found the example at this site: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations#apiresponses-apiresponse but it doesnt work :-(

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger Inheritance and Composition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27862407/swagger-inheritance-and-composition)

Comment: Same for C#, any idea?

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported in springfox yet.
See https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/868

Yes, it's confusing, since they do have annotations with attributes like "discriminator" and "subTypes", but they don't work.

UPDATE: the issue was closed in the meantime (in March 2018), and it should work in Springfox >= 2.9.0 (haven't tested it myself)