# swagger2 polymorphisme: add list of abstract classes to swagger documentation

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have a spring-boot application with swagger2. I want to be able to map a list of parent objects to my request model in swagger. I am using annotations atm but using a yaml file is also possible.

Say I have an abstract class Person and two child classes Child and Adult. In my request I have a list of Person's which can contain Child objects and Adult objects.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
      use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
      include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
      property = "type",
      visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
      @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child.class, name = "CHILD"),
      @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Adult.class, name = "ADULT")})
@ApiModel(value = "Child", subTypes = {Child.class, Adult.class}, discriminator = "type")
public abstract class Person { 
   @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Name of the person", example = "aaron")
   private String name;
   @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Birthdate of the person", example = "2000-07-10")
   private Date birthDate;
   @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Type of the person ('CHILD' or 'ADULT')", example = "CHILD")
   private String type;

   Child(String name, LocalDate birthdate) {
    this.name = name;
    this.birthdate = birthdate;
   }

   Child() {
   }
}

public class Adult extends Person { 
   private String job;

   public Adult(String name, Date birthdate, String job) {
      super(name, birthdate);
      this.job = job;
   }

   Adult() {
   }
}

public class Child extends Person { 
   private List<String> toys;

   public Child(String name, Date birthdate, List<String> toys) {
      super(name, birthdate);
      this.toys = toys;
   }

   Child() {
   }
}
```

My request object looks like:

```
public class PersonRequest {

@ApiModelProperty(notes = "Year of insert", example = "2019")
private Integer year;

@ApiModelProperty(notes = "Month of insert", example = "1")
private Integer month;

@ApiModelProperty(notes = "List of persons")
private List<Person> persons;

public SimulationRequest(Integer year, Integer month, List<Person> persons) {
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
    this.persons = persons;
}

private SimulationRequest() {
}

public Integer getYear() {
    return year;
}

public Integer getMonth() {
    return month;
}

public List<Person> getPersons() {
    return persons;
}
}
```

I am not able to get swagger-ui to show a correct model, what I'm getting now is:

```
PersonRequest {
  persons (Array[Person], optional): List of persons ,
  month (integer, optional): Month of insert ,
  year (integer, optional): Year of insert
}Person {
 name (string, optional): Birthdate of the person ,
 birthDate (string, optional): Name of the person ,
 type (string, optional): Type of the person ('CHILD' or 'ADULT')
}
```

What I want is something like:

```
PersonRequest {
  persons (Array[Person], optional): List of persons ,
  month (integer, optional): Month of insert ,
  year (integer, optional): Year of insert
}Child {
 name (string, optional): Birthdate of the person ,
 birthDate (string, optional): Name of the person ,
 type (string, optional): Type of the person ('CHILD' or 'ADULT')
 toys (Array[string], optional): Toys of the child
}Adult {
 name (string, optional): Birthdate of the person ,
 birthDate (string, optional): Name of the person ,
 type (string, optional): Type of the person ('CHILD' or 'ADULT')
 job (string, optional): Job of the adult
}
```

and with an example value

```
{
 "persons": [
  {
     "birthdate": "2000-07-10",
     "name": "aaron",
     "type": "CHILD",
     "toys" : ["ball","lego"]
  },
  {
     "birthdate": "1990-07-10",
     "name": "sofia",
     "type": "ADULT",
     "job" : "developer"
  }
],
"month": 6,
"year": 2019
}
```

I have searched in the documentation but don't seem to find the correct answer to my problem. I've looked at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27862407/swagger-inheritance-and-composition) and followed the petstore example in the swagger editor. But I don't seem to find how I can use a list/array of abstract classes in Swagger.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to this problem as well. Did you manage to find one?

Comment: I'm sorry this a rather old thread. I'm not sure if I was able to ever fix the actual problem. Wish I could help you further. I'm amazed that this still is an issue three years later.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my sample, using Lombok and Swagger 3 annotations. The trick is to use "oneOf" or "anyOf" on the collation with abstract type. See https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/ for details.

```
@Data
public class PersonRequest {

@Schema(description = "Either Child or Adult",
           anyOf = {Child .class, Adult.class})
private List<? extends Person> persons;

}

public enum PersonType {
        PARENT, CHILD
    }

@Data
public abstract class Person { 
   
   @Schema(notes = "Name of the person", example = "aaron")
   private String name;
   
   @Schema(notes = "Birthdate of the person", example = "2000-07-10")
   @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
   private Date birthDate;
   
   @Schema(notes = "Type of the person ('CHILD' or 'ADULT')", example = "CHILD")
   private PersonType type; //this should be one of the enum values

   Child(String name, LocalDate birthdate) {
    this.name = name;
    this.birthdate = birthdate;
   }

   Child() {
   }
}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Adult extends Person { 
   private String job;

   public Adult(String name, Date birthdate, String job) {
      super(name, birthdate);
      this.job = job;
   }

   Adult() {
   }
}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Child extends Person { 
   private List<String> toys;

   public Child(String name, Date birthdate, List<String> toys) {
      super(name, birthdate);
      this.toys = toys;
   }

   Child() {
   }
}
```