# How to dynacmicaly enable disable properties in swagger

Tags: swagger

We have two versions of Class XXX. In the version one it includes property x and excludes property y and in the second version x is excluded and y is included.

I'm not able to do that as I can not pass parameters to hidden property it expects a contsant expression.

This is the sample code I use, Here quantity is xx.

```
@ApiModelProperty(dataType = "Float", required = false, notes = "Item Sequence", position = 5, hidden = this.isOpenMapping)
    public Float getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
```

this.isOpenMapping is class attribute to distinguish whether version one or two.

How to fix this? If you need any more information please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

When working in `swagger` the closest thing you can achieve to address your question  is `polymorphism` of a class. Despite of the fact that this is not completely supported in `Swagger` it actually can work with a bit of effort in the autogen code. See [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/3904#issuecomment-251084523) for more details.

Using `polymorphism` you can dynamically create different response based on the requested entity type, sharing a common code base.

That said, consider to implement a `composition` and `inheritance` logic as well. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27862407/swagger-inheritance-and-composition) about Swagger Inheritance and Composition.