# OpenAPI / Swagger model inheritance with AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I'm attempting to implement an API defined in Swagger or OpenAPI 3.0 using AWS API Gateway.

One endpoint in this API takes an abstract base model (lets call it `Pet` to be consistent with the well-worn Swagger example), but actually expects a concrete model that is derived from `Pet`... `Dog` for example.

The concrete model can be determined by a `type` attribute on `Pet`.

The concrete model can add additional fields.

Of course, this a job for a `discriminator`:

```
definitions:
    Pet:
        discriminator: petType
        required:
        - name
        - petType # required for inheritance to work
        properties:
        name: 
            type: string
        petType:
            type: string
    Cat:
        allOf:
        - $ref: '#/definitions/Pet' # Cat has all properties of a Pet
        - properties: # extra properties only for cats
            huntingSkill:
                type: string
                default: lazy
                enum:
                - lazy
                - aggressive
    Dog:
        allOf:
        - $ref: '#/definitions/Pet' # Dog has all properties of a Pet
        - properties: # extra properties only for dogs
            packSize:
                description: The size of the pack the dog is from
                type: integer
```

(taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27862407/swagger-inheritance-and-composition))

**However**, AWS API Gateway doesn't support `discriminator` ([ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html#api-gateway-known-issues-rest-apis)).

OK, annoying, but maybe a workaround is to define the API with OpenAPI 3.0, and utilise `oneOf` in the schema:

```
paths:
    /pets:
        patch:
            requestBody:
                content:
                    application/json:
                        schema:
                            oneOf:
                                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Cat'
                                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Dog'
```

**However** (again), AWS API Gateway doesn't support `oneOf` either ([ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html#api-gateway-known-issues-rest-apis)).

Does anyone know how to implement a model schema of this nature with AWS API Gateway, in particular to take advantage of body validation for an inheritance pattern (`Pet <- Dog`)? Or indeed a workaround without having to have methods for every concrete type?

Comment: any solution to this yet?

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen - not that I am aware of. We have moved away from using AWS API Gateway because there is too many of this inconsistencies and issues.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to add another answer, which is solving the issue in prettier way! The key problem is that in previous attempts I used OpenAPI 3.0.0, however 3.0.1 no longer seem to have any trouble with `oneOf` directive.

Here's the working example:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    // (...)
  },
  "paths": {
    "/pets": {
      "post": {
        "summary": "Post a pet",
        "requestBody": {
          "required": true,
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/PetRequest"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses": {
          "201": {
            // (...)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "Cat": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "cat_stuff"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "cat_stuff": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "Dog": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "dog_stuff"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "dog_stuff": {
            "type": "string"
          },
        }
      },
      "PetRequest": {
        "oneOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Cat"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Dog"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    // Many fields omitted (...)
}
```

Curling with payload that doesn't match one of those schemas gives following error, which proves that the `oneOf` is working as expected!

```
(...)
"error_messages": [
    "[instance failed to match exactly one schema (matched 0 out of 2)]"
],
```

Please test this yourself and leave some feedback.

Comment: Basically, the solution is instead of using `oneOf` right under `content: application/json: schema:`, wrap the response as a model (create a model in the `components` section), and use the `oneOf` in your model. That works! Now the API Gateway exported yaml will show the correct oneOf.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be fully satisfactory answer to your question, but there is a way to use `oneOf` with API Gateway. [You can use JSON schema for individual models according to AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/model-api-gateway/).

Thanks to that fact you can update your models after API Gateway has been deployed.

```
# Reformatted here for readability
VALUE='"{\"$schema\": \"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#\",
         \"title\": \"A Pet Request\",
         \"oneOf\":
        [{ \"$ref\": \"https://apigateway.amazonaws.com/restapis/xxxxxxx/models/Cat\" },
         { \"$ref\": \"https://apigateway.amazonaws.com/restapis/xxxxxxx/models/Dog\" }]}"'


aws apigateway update-model \
--rest-api-id xxxxxxx \
--model-name 'PetRequest' \
--patch-operations "op=replace,path=/schema,value=${VALUE}"
```

This solution works, however might not be greatly sustainable, since you need to execute the `patch-operations` after each deployment.

I'll likely update this answer if I find better way.